# Prevent deleting single row in SQL Server but let other rows be deleted in same transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete, database-trigger

Lets say I have the following table:

```
PKID | UID | FKID
-----------------
1    | ABC | 1
2    | BCD | 2
3    | CDE | 2
4    | DEF | 1
5    | EFG | 3
```

What I want to do is block deletes with a trigger (or other way if there is a better way to do this) but only for the rows where FKID = 1 but still allow other rows to be deleted. So, if someone types `DELETE FROM sampleTable` I would want only rows 2, 3, and 5 to be deleted, and 1 and 4 should remain.

Comment: uh, why not `delete from yourtable where fkid <> 1`?

Comment: This is weird requirement, but if you want to do that, using "INSTED OF"  trigger is the only way you can go. Would you pleas tell why your want to do that?

Comment: Need to understand your use case better here.  Who is the "someone" that can type the DELETE statement you are concerned with?

Comment: Funny thing about that obvious solution, Marc B, is that we have no idea what the hell is actually deleting records out of the table.  We have a process that deletes/inserts records from the table periodically to synchronize it with another datasource, however, somehow records that should never be getting deleted are being deleted anyway and we can't figure out why at the moment. The current solution is to ad hoc insert them back into the table.  I'm trying to stop it from happening.

Comment: I'm sure you've already thought of this, but one way to catch the ofending query/app/user is to run a trace via [SQL Server's Profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

Comment: @user3657661, are the same exact records getting deleted every time? if in future this happens for some other records, are you going to consider them as well? How are you syncing the data? Are you using a custom tool? If so, there might be bug on the tool. As suggested, try to find the offensive query, or use reliable sync mechanism.

Comment: I don't know if they're the exact same records, but they're supposed to represent top-level users that are manually provisioned and so I can identify which ones they are because during provisioning, they are tagged with a specific Foreign Key that is only used for manually provisioned users.  I don't have access to all the code as it's a system that integrates with a 3rd party application that we don't own.  That said, they've identified some bugs and are releasing a new version soon.  I will see if we can add profiling tracing to find out what's doing it and address it at the source, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_tablename_delete ON dbo.tablename
    FOR DELETE
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted WHERE FKID = 1)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Cannot delete this record!', 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT
            ROLLBACK
        END

        SET NOCOUNT OFF
    GO
```